# When mapping (automapper) need to convert a type enum to a bool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have the following **model**:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int      FooID { get; set; }
    public string   Description { get; set; }
    public bool     IsValid{ get; set; }
}
```

I have the following **view model**:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public YesNoEnumViewModel IsValid{ get; set; }
}
```

For the type YesNoEnumViewModel I used the following enum:

```
public enum YesNoEnumViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Yes", ResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    Yes = 1,
    [Display(Name = "No", ResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    No = 2
}
```

In my code I need to map my viewModel into my model. So I try this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddedNew(FooViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return PartialView("AddedNew", viewModel);

        var foo = Mapper.Map<FooViewModel, FooModel>(viewModel);
        ...
    }
```

And I got an error when trying to map. The error is on the converting from the enum type YesNoEnumViewModel to bool (the property in my model is of type bool).

Here is my CreateMap:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FooViewModel, Foo>();
```

Maybe I need to specify in the CreateMap that for member **IsValid** of my FooViewModel something special must be done to convert it to a bool of my model?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Maybe I need to specify in the CreateMap that for member IsValid of my FooViewModel something special must be done to convert it to a bool of my model?"

Exactly, you need to create a custom Resolver that knows how to resolve YesNoEnumViewModel to Boolean:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FooViewModel, Foo>().
     ForMember(dest => dest.IsValid, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<EnumResolver>());

internal class EnumResolver : ValueResolver<FooViewModel, bool>
{
    protected override bool ResolveCore(FooViewModel vm)
    {
        return vm.IsValid == YesNoEnumViewModel.Yes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I have a property IsValid1 and IsValid2? How to use the resolver in this scenario because in the EnumResolver we only have one return (defined here for IsValid)?

Comment: Just create more mappings in CreateMap:  ForMember(dest => dest.IsValid1, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<EnumResolver>()).ForMember(dest => dest.IsValid2, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<EnumResolver>());

Comment: The problem is the return value in the ResolveCore which is always returning for the same property (here IsValid) but for the scenario where we have IsValid1 and IsValid2: what to return?

Comment: Oh you mean IsValid1 and IsValid2 are properties on Foo?  In that case just create a new resolver for the additional property.  There might be a better way of doing it since this does bloat your code, but I don't know of it.