# Would like to convert enum type to bool when mapping for 2 properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have the following **model**:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int      FooID { get; set; }
    public string   Description { get; set; }
    public bool     IsValid { get; set; }
    public bool     IsFollowed { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following **view model**:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public YesNoEnumViewModel IsValid { get; set; }
    public YesNoEnumViewModel IsFollowed { get; set; }
}
```

For the type YesNoEnumViewModel I used the following enum:

```
public enum YesNoEnumViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Yes", ResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    Yes = 1,
    [Display(Name = "No", ResourceType = typeof(UserResource))]
    No = 2
}
```

In my code I need to map my viewModel into my model. So I try this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddedNew(FooViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return PartialView("AddedNew", viewModel);

        var foo = Mapper.Map<FooViewModel, FooModel>(viewModel);
        ...
    }
```

And I got an error when trying to map. The error is on the converting from the enum type YesNoEnumViewModel to bool (the property in my model is of type bool).

Here is my CreateMap:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FooViewModel, Foo>();
```

Maybe I need to specify in the CreateMap that for members **IsValid** and **IsFollowed** of my FooViewModel something special must be done to convert it to a bool of my model?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When mapping (automapper) need to convert a type enum to a bool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382409/when-mapping-automapper-need-to-convert-a-type-enum-to-a-bool)

Comment: This question is about converting multiple properties of type enum.

Comment: @Bronzato Didn't you just ask a nearly identical question about this not too long ago?

Comment: @Bronzato: You should be able to adapt the answer you got in the first question to your problem now. The number of properties you have to map really doesn't impact the root of the question.

Comment: I'll investigate. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper cannot possibly know the semantics behind your enum, so you cannot expect it to map this without any help from you. You need to specify how to convert your custom enum to boolean when configuring your mapping:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<FooViewModel, Foo>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.IsValid,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsValid == YesNoEnumViewModel.Yes ? true : false)
    )
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.IsFollowed,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsFollowed == YesNoEnumViewModel.Yes ? true : false)
    );
```

and to DRY:

```
private static bool ToBool(YesNoEnumViewModel model)
{
    return model == YesNoEnumViewModel.Yes ? true : false;
}
```

and then:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<FooViewModel, Foo>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.IsValid,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ToBool(src.IsValid))
    )
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.IsFollowed,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ToBool(src.IsFollowed))
    );
```

Or you could also use a [custom value resolver](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers).

Comment: Thank you this is much more clean than what I did. Just one question: I understand very well 'dest' is for destination and 'src' is for source but what is the signification of 'opt'?